# Starting a new religion in India

Tags: india, indian-constitutional-law, religious-law, freedom-of-religion

#### Context

Indian constitution provides fundamental right to freedom of religion (Article 25,26,27,28 among others).

India is country with secular constitution. However many personal laws regarding marriages, divorce, inheritance, adoption etc are religion specific (along with some non-religious versions of these acts like Special Marriage Act)

#### Questions

1. *Does the constitution of India allows starting a brand new religion?*
2. *Will this new religion get similar freedoms? Especially if it promotes controversial practices (which are not uncommon in many religions like — circumcision, polygamy, subjugation of women, weird dress codes etc)*

Comment: 3 out of 4 tenets you suggested are against the law.

Comment: In Indian context : Not giving women the proper rights to inherit property (for example son gets bigger share than that of daughter), under _Digambara_ sect of Jainism monks remain naked, polygamy for certain religions — allowed.

Comment: Circumcision is mutilation and a crime, Polygamy is banned and subjugation is enslavement and illegal. You mean a *different inheritance law* which is legal, but not subjugation

Comment: _Subjugation of women_ under religions is a real thing. And I used this term to highlight social discriminations and suppressions which continue under _personal laws_ . (Which vary religion to religion). However I don't might removing this term.

Comment: Male circumcision is lawful, FGM is not.

Comment: @Trish Muslim Personal Law still allows polygamy

Comment: @whoisit not under the indian laws. Religious laws have to bend to state laws.

Comment: @Trish Nope. The Muslim Personal law allows it and so do the courts - no other law has declared polygamy illegal for muslims. Polygamy is disallowed in a few other religious laws, and for interfaith/atheist marriages - but not for Muslims. Polygamy is still quite common among Indian Muslims - although the societal acceptance is waning.

Comment: @whoisit reread, indeed, but that is **explicitly** only for Muslims, not any new or different religion. By being *not* Muslim, the law does say the religion would violate law.

Comment: @whoisit unless a law specifies different, the general prohibition of [IPC 494 applies](https://indiankanoon.org/doc/508426) - For Hindus, it was [specifically abrogated](https://indiankanoon.org/doc/446436/) by voiding previous law that would have allowed it and never reinstating it. [In this 2008](https://indiankanoon.org/docfragment/225302/?formInput=polygamy) extract from a court opinion in a case reg. a Muslim marriage, section 8 is of note. The case does discuss the legality of Muslim polygamy, but in the context of a 2nd marriage raising grounds for dissolution of the first by the wife.

Comment: Or more specifically, [this court oinion](https://indiankanoon.org/docfragment/402156/?formInput=polygamy) calls out in section 20 that it is **only** the *Muslim Personal Law (Shariat) Application Act, 1937* that allows it, meaning unless there would be a separate law for the new religion it is illegal as a fallback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the constitution of India allows starting a brand new religion?

Yes. Indeed, brand new religions have been started in India since it was enacted. *See, e.g.*, [Dinkoism](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/all-you-wanted-to-know-about-indias-brand-new-religion-dinkoism/articleshow/51711172.cms) and an academic journal article by [Dubey (2015)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/26290776) discussing several others. The [Lingayat religion](https://thediplomat.com/2018/03/a-new-religion-in-india-karnatakas-lingayats-seek-recognition/#:%7E:text=Religion%20in%20India%3F-,Karnataka%27s%20Lingayats%20Seek%20Recognition,religion%20tag%20to%20the%20Lingayats.&text=A%20new%20religion%20has%20the,of%20existing%20and%20practicing%20religions.) is currently in the process of seeking official government recognition as an organized religious body (even though it has actually existed for centuries in India).

> Will this new religion get similar freedoms?

Yes.

> Especially if it promotes controversial practices (which are not
> uncommon in many religions like — circumcision, polygamy, subjugation
> of women, weird dress codes etc)

The fact that practices are controversial does not bar a religion from receiving respect under the Constitution of India. But religious views don't always overcome secular law.

For example, a new religion that called for human sacrifice would not make that practice legal in India, despite its constitutional protections for freedom of religion.